# Cross platform development (Windows Mobile, Windows Phone, iOS, Android)

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write once deploy on Windows Mobile 6, Windows Phone 7, Android and iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189616/write-once-deploy-on-windows-mobile-6-windows-phone-7-android-and-iphone)

Was just wondering if there were any cross platform development platforms which would run great for corporate type apps on various mobile devices.

Would be ideal if the language was C# but feel free to suggest others.