# Develop a C# application for Windows Mobile, Android & iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a project where I need to build a C# application that is able to run in iPhone, Android and Windows Mobile.

For windows Mobile that is no problem, but I think its a challenge when we try to develop for Android and iPhone.

I've been searching for solutions and i found some information about [Mono-Android](http://mono-android.net/) and [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/).

My question is, has anyone used this API's? Are they good? 
Do they really take advantage of Android/iPhone native api's? 
Can I with only one source code create an application for both platforms?

And finally, is there any other way of creating a C# application for these mobile platforms?

Comment: Note regarding monodroid: the required runtime is currently over 30 megabytes in size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write once deploy on Windows Mobile 6, Windows Phone 7, Android and iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189616/write-once-deploy-on-windows-mobile-6-windows-phone-7-android-and-iphone)

Comment: This article might be of interest to you: http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/04/Mono-iPad

Comment: Brad in that question there are a lot of suggestion on how to develop a cross platform in other languages, I really need to be in C# and I asked for feedback for this specific API's (Monotouch and MonoDroid)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes they are very solid.  They give you .NET 4.0 with all of that capability & the ability to share data access, networking/API integration, and business logic in shared assemblies.  You'll of course have to write the user interface portion of the applications in C# but specific to the platform.

For example, MonoTouch is like Cocoa in C#.  It will feel unlike your typical .NET programming style, so make sure you get comfortable reading Objective-C for documentation & assistance.

Also recommended is to follow the UI guidelines of the platform in question.  Don't create a cookie cutter app for all platforms or it will suck everywhere.