# Adobe Flash builder iOS app vs native iOS App

Tags: iphone, flash, adobe, air, flash-builder

I recently came to know about the adobe flash builder with flex in latest release it supports to achieve the benefits of flash for iOS apps.As i am looking for a calendar based app,before taking the Adobe flash builder as a solution, i would like to be clear on the following queries.

1. What limitation is there of the ipa file generated from FB 4.5 as
   opposed to a core COCOA touch based solution
2. What are the performance differences between the FlashBuilder app
   and natively built iPhone app.
3. Is there any limitation of building a HTML5 based app given the
   calendar functionality  apart from  look and Feel.

Thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) You won't have complete API integration and what integration there is will be quite a bit behind the latest iOS version.

2)The app will be considerably slower and much more resource intensive. How much so depends on how much the app does. However, even a small app will be surprisingly large and resource intensive because it will have to support the entire flash stack just to display "hello world".

3) It depends on what "calendar functionality" you mean. You should be able to call the Calendar Access from javascript just as you would with a widget.

I generally discourage people from using cross-platform tools for all but he most trivial apps. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369413/developing-cross-platform-mobile-application/3619544#3619544) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326110/are-there-any-huge-differences-between-objective-c-and-java-or-iphone-and-androi/3365800#3365800) previous answers for details. As a rough rule of thumb, if your app would work as a web page, then you can use cross-platform, otherwise you will end up with a vastly inferior app.

The best reason to use cross-platform tools is if the end users gains significant utility having the app run on many platforms. If you chose cross-platform because it makes the developers life easier, the app will most likely fail in the marketplace.

Comment: Well put. I am using Flash Builder to develop cross-platform apps but only because they are purpose built form systems for a specific company. If I were developing an app for the general public I would choose a platform. I can confirm the apps are slower and lack certain native abilities. For us the fact that they will interface with the Main website and can run on iOS and Android, and even as packaged air programs on Windows made the benefits well out way the losses.